# SIGABRT when accessing NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

I have a method that is called every time the devices location updates with statements below included:

Just curious as to why I'm getting a SIGABRT signal from this PrevSpeedDic here:

```
if (DriveInfoDic != nil) {
    PrevSpeedDic = [DriveInfoDic objectForKey: @"speed"];
} else {
    DriveInfoDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
}
```

But when I move this above the statement above it works fine as it should. My variables are defined correctly or it would not work in any circumstance.

```
  DriveInfoDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [NSNumber numberWithDouble:speedMPH], @"speed", nil];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local variables are not initialized to 0 (nil) by default. If you don't set DriveInfoDic before that if, it's going to take the first branch and crash.

Comment: if you are targeting iOS 5, you should be using ARC (wherein local variables are initialized to nil).  Note that ARC is not under NDA, but any specifics of iOS 5's APIs and dev tools are.